# Read QDateTime from QDataStream giving null

Tags: qt, qdatetime, qdatastream

I have the following region of data being read into a QDataStream object :

```
DE 07 05 19 0E 28 1A
```

This should translate to the date/time: `25-05-2014 15:40:26`

I am trying to use the following to read this into a QDateTime variable:

```
QFile fileIn(iFile);
if (!fileIn.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) return;
QDataStream data(&fileIn);
data.setByteOrder(QDataStream::LittleEndian);
data.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_5_0);
data.skipRawData(32);

.
.
QDateTime time;
data >> time;
qDebug () << time.date();
```

Instead I get null/blank in time.
Output is:

```
QDate("")
```

Comment: How was the data created? Can you give a minimal example that serializes the date, and then deserializes it?

Comment: I can't give an example of how the data was serialized as I am reverse engineering this data. I will amend the question with more of my code.

Comment: Was the data serialized using QDataStream/its protocol at all? If not, it makes no sense to use QDataStream.

Comment: I assume so. I am able to extract other data for qString, qint8, quint16, even QList OK.

Comment: Have you tried to serialize `25-05-2014 15:40:26` from Qt code? Do you acually end up with `DE 07 05 19 0E 28 1A`? If not, no reason it will work the way around...

Comment: @jpo38. No I haven't tried that. I should clarify I don't expect the data formatting to be present/the same, but I think QDateTime should take care of that. I doubt this is an environment issue since the data files I am processing are multi-platform.

Comment: But how did you get `DE 07 05 19 0E 28 1A` in the first place?

Comment: @peppe, the data is in files from an application for which I am investigating whether an import feature can be added to our system to support it. Based on other regions in the file I am able to use direct read into quint8, qint16, qint32 and qstring variables from the file/QDataStream, so I assume I just need to find an appropriate type. Which is why I tried QDateTime. I can of course  just each bit e.g. qint16 yyyy = getInt16(data), etc, then join it all together, so I do have a workaround.

Comment: The fact is that serialization through `QDataStream` of a `qint16` is "just" writing its contents as two bytes (in a given endianess). That's pretty much compatible with anything else that uses the same. But the serialization of a `QDateTime` is [way more complicated](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/datastreamformat.html) and very specific to Qt. Unless you produced the bytes with the same semantics, you can't read them back with `QDataStream` (how could Qt know the meaning of the bytes in the stream?). Deserialize "properly" given the writer semantics, and then reassemble a `QDateTime`.

Comment: OK. It seems that I should stick with the method I have used for this type of data, i.e. read the yyyy, mm, dd, hh, mi, ss separately. Thanks all for your responses .

Answer (score 0):

The first thing here is how on earth this data is serialised. I've had a look and can't work it out: each byte doesn't nicely convert to each part of date/time, the bytes you are trying to reverse engineer aren't the epoch value of that date converted into hex. You can't expect `QDateTime` to magically know your raw data format. Report back with data format and I'll try and help.

Comment: As with the other responses, it seems that I should stick with the method I have used for this type of data, i.e. read the yyyy, mm, dd, hh, mi, ss separately. Thank you for your help.